# Eclipse PDE: put hints on java editor

Tags: findbugs, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to create an Eclipse plug-in, which gives suggestions about in which packages the classes should be. And now I'm having troubles on adding corresponding icons to the java editor, on the left side of the package declaration.
To be more specific, now the user can run the algorithm from the context menu and what I want is to add suggestions on each java class file (similar to the way that FindBugs works). And if the user clicks on that icon, there must be a hint (I guess they are called Proposals) saying "move to package 'anotherpackage'"; after clicking on it the class will be moved to that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [create problem markers](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_problem_markers_for_my_compiler%3F) for the icons and afterwards you implement [matching quick fixes](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_implement_Quick_Fixes_for_my_own_language%3F) for the tooltips to solve the problems.

Comment: Thanks, and here is the [The Mark Words](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html) article for more details about the markers.